# Generalizing Haskell: could we replace Hask with Cat?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

It is great that Haskell allows us to walk around in the category Hask. But sometimes I feel it is too tight. So I had this idea about a programming language that would allow us to move around in the category Cat of small categories, where categories would be types and functors from categories C to D would be  functions of type C->D. At first it seemed a crazy idea, but I found an [article](http://www.brics.dk/RS/01/27/) by Glynn Winskel and his student Mario Jose Cáccamo about such calculus! However it is limited to a fragment of Cat. Do you think that it would be possible to extend Haskell in this spirit, i.e., instead of working in the category Hask, it would work in the category (or better, 2-category) Cat? Are you aware of any calculus similar to the one by Cáccamo and Winskel?

http://www.brics.dk/RS/01/27/

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3721/programming-languages-based-on-category-theory).

Comment: And I'm too late to point out [Charity](http://pll.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/charity1/www/home.html)... still, since the content of the site seems to be broken (for me, at least?), [here's](http://ge.tt/6NXr5un1/v/0) a link to its user manual.

Comment: Thanks @phg. But I already knew about Charity and it is not what I am looking for. Although it completely grounded in category theory, it works in its own specific category like Haskell in Hask.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. Although it is a related question, I cannot find the sought answer there.

Comment: Would this be a better question for CS.stackexchange.com, since it is more theoretical in nature?

Comment: Thanks @stonemetal. I didn't know this forum. I'll consider it next time.

Comment: I moved this question there: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25293/generalizing-haskell-could-we-replace-hask-with-cat

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because per discussion it is better suited for cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth: This question has generated much more interest here that on cstheory.stackexchange.com. Probably it should be deleted there. And it *is* definitely a question about programming.

Comment: OK with me either way.